# How do you print out a value from wx.TextCtrl?

Tags: python, textbox, wxwidgets, wx.textctrl

I have something like this right now:

```
import wx

class QuickAddBox(wx.TextCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, viewer):
        self.quick_add_text = wx.TextCtrl.__init__(self, parent, -1, '', size=(300,20), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.OnPress, self.quick_add_text)

    def OnPress(self, evt):
        print self.quick_add_text.GetValue()
```

And I want to get the value of the textbox when I click enter. But when I do click enter, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetValue'
```

Any advice?

__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__-

Nevermind I solved it by doing the following:

```
def OnPress(self, evt):
    print self.GetValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're storing the return value of TextCtrl's `__init__` (which is `None`) instead of the actual class instance.  Your `__init__` should likely look like this:

```
class QuickAddBox(wx.TextCtrl):
    def __init__(self, parent, viewer):
        self.quick_add_text = wx.TextCtrl(self, parent, -1, '', size=(300,20), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
```

Comment: If I do that, I get this error:

TypeError: in method 'new_TextCtrl', expected argument 1 of type 'wxWindow *'

Comment: My code is part of some huge overall code so I'm not sure how much more information I can give you without handing over lots of code.